# Mediarecorder video size issue

Tags: android, resolution, mediarecorder

I am experiencing some issues with the mediarecorder.

I am trying to record in 320x480 video size/resolution but whenever i try to do that it gives me invalid size error. 1920 x 1080 works just fine.

Mediarecorder code:

```
    setRecordingSize();

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(RECORD_WIDTH, RECORD_HEIGHT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(8 * 1000000); 
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
```

Set recording size method:

```
   String values = getPreferenceListPreferenceString("VIDEO_RESOLUTION", "1920 x 1080 (phone/tablet)");

    if(values == "2560 x 1600 (tablet)")
    {
        setRecordSize(2560, 1600);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "2560 x 1440 (tablet)")
    {
        setRecordSize(2560, 1440);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "2048 x 1536 (tablet)")
    {
        setRecordSize(2048, 1536);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "1920 x 1080 (phone/tablet)")
    {
        setRecordSize(1920, 1080);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "1280 x 800  (tablet)")
    {
        setRecordSize(1280, 800);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "1280 x 720  (phone)")
    {
        setRecordSize(1280, 720);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "1024 x 600  (tablet)")
    {
        setRecordSize(1024, 600);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "540 x 960   (phone)")
    {
        setRecordSize(540, 960);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "480 x 854   (phone)")
    {
        setRecordSize(480, 854);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "480 x 800   (phone)")
    {
        setRecordSize(480, 800);
        return;
    }

    if(values == "320 x 480   (phone)")
    {
        setRecordSize(320, 480);
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR, VALUES: " + values, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Set record size method:

```
public void setRecordSize(int width, int height)
{
    RECORD_WIDTH = width;

    RECORD_HEIGHT = height;
}
```

I cannot find the problem should work fine.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good chance that MediaRecorder does not support 320x480 resolution. You can try to parse /system/etc/media_profiles.xml to get list of supported resolutions (although this file does not exist on some buggy devices).